# Combinations of consecutive elements of an array

Tags: ruby

Is there any builtin method to produce combinations of consecutive array elements?

```
a = ['1','2','3','4']
# => '12','23','34'
```

I tried the methods `permutation`, `combination`, and `each_slice`, but was not able to produce required output.

```
a.permutation(2).to_a #=> [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,1],[2,3],[2,4],[3,1],[3,2],[3,4]]
a.combination(2).to_a  #=> [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]
a.each_slice(2) {|a| p a} #=> ["1", "2"],["3", "4"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can do it with a combination of a few methods.

```
a.each_cons(2).map(&:join)
# => ["12", "23", "34"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will look more into enumerables. :)